# How to load a modified superclass in Java?

Tags: java, classloader, superclass, java-bytecode-asm

- I have a class A extends B.
- I've created a CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader to use `defineClass(className, byte[], offset, length)`.
- I've instanciate a `new CustomClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())`.
  So the parent of my CustomClassLoader is the ClassLoader from the current thread.
- I've modified B class using ASM framework. I've write my modified class in a .class file and use a decompiler to be sure it works. And it works.
- I've added modified B class to my CustomClassLoader
- I've set the `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader()` with my CustomClassLoader.
- I've load A using `Class.forName(String, true, the CustomClassLoader)`.
- But the loaded B class seems to be the orginal class.

What did I wrong ?
If you need more info, a detailed topic is on my [GitHub](https://github.com/EyZox/DEBUG-Need-help-about-classloader/tree/master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java classloaders *first* search the parent classloader before looking in the child.

> The loadClass method in ClassLoader performs these tasks, in order,
>   when called to load a class:
>
> 1. If a class has already been loaded, it returns it.
> 2. **Otherwise, it delegates the search for the new class to the parent class loader.**
> 3. If the parent class loader does not find the class, loadClass calls the method findClass to find and load the class.
>
> ([Understanding Extension Class Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html) - Oracle)

If you want to change that order, you need to override the `loadClass` method as well but there are many caveats and it's not advisable unless you understand classloading very well.

- The easier option is to make sure that the parent class loader cannot find the original class `B`.

Comment: "A" class is not loaded so ClassLoader child delegates A classloading to the ClassLoader parent.
But B is loaded in child (the modified version is loaded in child), so when A require B because A extends B why B is loaded from the parent (which load the original) ?

Comment: What do you mean with "But B is loaded in child" ? If B exists in the parent class loader, then it's not loaded in the child, because every classloader that doesn't override `loadClass` first delegates to its parent, and will only try to load it in the child classlaoder if it's not found in the parent

Comment: I have to change B class bytecode at the runtime.
So to save my modified B class, I have to use child.defineClass() because parent.defineClass() is not visible and the original B class may exist in parent classloader.

- B is modified and loaded to child
- A is loaded from child -> delegate to parent
- A extends B
- B seems to be loaded from the parent
- B is not saved to the parent, so parent load B using URL I think
- parent load the orginal B class

- B is loaded twice : original in parent and modified in child.

Comment: I've use [this](https://gist.github.com/EyZox/34df5a81a05bdadd41aecd942894ba3b) to solve my issue. I hope this is not too much dirty :/

Answer (score 2):

There are several things to know:

- For most things, dealing with the thread’s context class loader is obsolete, as it has no impact. It’s more like a convention; setting it has an impact if there’s some other code querying and using it. For the standard class loading process, it doesn’t have any meaning. It’s unfortunate that the documentation doesn’t mention that and make it look like a relevant thing. Perhaps, it was intended to have more meaning when it was added.
- As [pointed out by Erwin Bolwidt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38649308/2711488), when loading `A` via your custom loader, it will delegate to its parent loader, returning a class `A` loaded by the parent.
- When *resolving* class references, the JVM will always use the *defining* loader of the referrer. So when the reference from `A` to `B` is resolved, the JVM will always use the parent loader which defined the class `A`

The last point implies that even if you modify your custom class loader to look up its own classes first instead of following the standard model of querying the parent first, it doesn’t solve the issue if it has no own `A`, as then, it still returns the parent’s `A` whose references will be resolved using the parent. Since you are invoking `defineClass` before asking for `A`, the lookup order doesn’t matter at all, as your custom loader has an already defined `B` that it returned if anyone ever asked it for `B`…

So you could let your custom loader also load and define `A`. Or you use Reflection with access override to `defineClass` on the system `ClassLoader` before it loads `B`. The cleanest solution is to implement the class modification logic as a Java Agent which can use the Instrumentation API to intercept and change the definition of `B` right at its loading time.